# Zabbix with Fortimanager

Tags: snmp, fortigate, monitoring, fortinet

I am seeking assistance with configuring Zabbix to monitor FortiGates that are managed by FortiManager. Despite configuring FortiManager with SNMP and adding a host for it in Zabbix, I am not seeing any results in monitoring the managed FortiGates(8 of them). I am curious if this is a feasible configuration.
aka I want to add just fortimanager and want all of my fortigates to be detected and then monitored, i found templates online that cna monitor but i could first try it with the fortigate SNMP/Http template.

Additionally, I attempted to enable SNMP on one of the FortiGate interfaces and added the corresponding SNMP settings with the same community ID used in FortiManager. Unfortunately, no observable changes occurred. I am wondering if installing a Zabbix agent on the FortiManager machine is necessary to collect logs from all FortiGates. Alternatively, should I add each FortiGate individually to Zabbix as separate hosts?
is there any solution without adding host by host? thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that FortiManager channels the desired SNMP data or represents them with its own MIB - perhaps you just need to install its MIB in Zabbix though. Alternatively, I'd add each FortiGate individually.